# Disable submit button on first click with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit-button

I currently have a lightbox popup attached to a submit button that shows only the first time the submit button is clicked. Basically before someone submits a form, we want them to see this popup when they hit the submit button. And that all works fine, but now I need to make it to where on that first click, the form doesn't submit/process. However, after that first click, the submit button would need to be enabled to where they can submit the form.

Any idea how to change the below code to where the submit button does not process the form only the first time the submit button is clicked?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Submitbutton').one("click",function(e) {

    $('#lp').lightbox_me({
    centered: true,
    overlayCSS:{background: '#481d33', opacity: .45},
    overlaySpeed:0,
    lightboxSpeed:0
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you show more  sample code? or express details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var hasClicked = false;
$('#Submitbutton').on('click',function(e) {
    if (hasClicked === true) {
        //submit form here
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        hasClicked = true;
        $('#lp').lightbox_me({
            centered: true,
            overlayCSS:{background: '#481d33', opacity: .45},
            overlaySpeed:0,
            lightboxSpeed:0
        });
    }
});
```

Sets a variable on first submit, then on second submit does something different because of that variable.

**Edit:** Consistent quotes and code cleanup.

Comment: Your code will not work as you are only listening for the click once.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the one, just changed it to on :D

Comment: This is best answer. It uses a bool (small memory footprint), it covers your lightbox code, and it is fast.
The only thing I'd do to improve it is if you're using a form element bind to submit of the form instead of click of the submit.

Answer (score 1):

Change `.on()` from `.one()`. You can declare a variable to track whether button was clicked or not.

```
var isAlreadytClicked = false;
$('#Submitbutton').on("click", function (e) {
    if (isAlreadytClicked == false) {
        isAlreadytClicked = true;
        return;
    }

    if (isAlreadytClicked) {
        //Do whatever you want on subsequent click

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add the line

`$('#SubmitBtn').attr('disabled',false);`

inside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the counter to determine clicked count:

```
 var count = 0;
 $('#Submitbutton').click(function(e) {
 count++;
 if(count==1)
 return;//return if clicked first time
 $('#lp').lightbox_me({centered: true,overlayCSS:{background: '#481d33', opacity: .45},overlaySpeed:0,lightboxSpeed:0});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button"  id="SubmitBtn" value="Submit" onclick="return submitData();" disabled="disabled" >
```

In Script

```
//create a global variable for clicked or not
var submitBtnClicked = false;

function submitData()
{
 if(submitBtnClicked )
 {
   $('#SubmitBtn').attr('disabled',false);
   submitBtnClicked =true;
 }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simply a return false should do. 
alternatively e.perventDefault() may help for event bubbling.

```
  $('#Submitbutton').one("click",function(e) {

     $('#lp').lightbox_me({
     centered: true,
     overlayCSS:{background: '#481d33', opacity: .45},
     overlaySpeed:0,
     lightboxSpeed:0
     });
    e.perventDefault();
     return false;
  });
```

Comment: .one() should run the function  once