# Disable click on button when clicking multiple times with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a button click with triggering first click and second click. So when clicking multiple times animation crushed.

Is there a way to disable click during the animation and enable only when animation completes?

See below my code with prop disbled which is not working properly

```
jQuery('.start_button').click(function(event){
    jQuery(this).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
    if(clickcount === 0){
        jQuery(this).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
        wheelForuneAnim.startAnimation();
        jQuery(this).find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        clickcount = 1;
    } 
    else if(clickcount === 1){
        jQuery(this).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
        wheelForuneAnim.stopFull();
        setTimeout(function(){
            wheelForuneAnim.stopAnimation();
        }, 700);
        clickcount = 0;

    }; 
});
```

Here is the markup

```
<div class="start_button">
      <button type="button"></button>  
</div>
```

Methods

```
startAnimation = function () {
        interval = setInterval(this.animation, 250);
    };
animation = function () {
        if((wheelelement % elems.length)==0){ wheelelement = 0 ;}
        elems.removeClass('active_wheel');
        jQuery('.game_wheel_item:eq('+wheelelement+')').addClass('active_wheel');
        wheelelement++;
    };
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: JQuery(this) is a div inside which i have a <button> @Satpal

Comment: So `.start_button` is a badly named `div` element that contains a button? It would help to see your actual HTML here.

Comment: See updated question @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @Satpal setTimeout method itself having callback, i think that's enough to solve the problem

Comment: So how i can fix this properly? @Satpal

Comment: here is the actual link from where @AnahitDEV copied the code, I suppose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646891/disable-submit-button-on-first-click-with-jquery   You can check the link and give credit to the user in the link if it helps you in solving the problem

Comment: @Satpal i tried to use call back but seems am doing something wrong. Any idea how to do it properly per my code and methods? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need that much of code, below code solve your problem

```
jQuery('.start_button').on('click','button',function(event){
    jQuery(this).off('click','button');

       wheelForuneAnim.startAnimation(function()
       {
            // do your second if stuff
           setTimeout(function(){
                 wheelForuneAnim.stopAnimation(function()
                 {
                       // after function finished executing do some stuff here
                 });
                 jQuery(this).on('click','button');
            }, 700); 
       });
});
```

your Methods

```
startAnimation = function (cbck) {
        interval = setInterval(this.animation, 250);
        if(cbck)
        {
           cbck();
        }
    };
stopanimation = function (cbck) {
        if((wheelelement % elems.length)==0){ wheelelement = 0 ;}
        elems.removeClass('active_wheel');
        jQuery('.game_wheel_item:eq('+wheelelement+')').addClass('active_wheel');
        wheelelement++;

       if(cbck)
           cbck();
    };
```

Comment: Why `setTimeout`?

Comment: When adding to my if statements on and off it is not working properly @Keerthivasan

Comment: please provide the links (reference), so the credit goes to actual user who provided the code and just don't copy and post the answer .

Comment: @Anahit DEV why you still need the if statement ?

Comment: Cause i have 2 different actions on first click and on second click. If you check my code snippet you will see @Keerthivasan

Comment: @AnahitDEV answer edited, dont use if else if, only one condition will ececute, in ur case its not suitable

Comment: Tested and not working @Keerthivasan. Also there is an error in console

Comment: my second if will not work like that cause second click must be triggered. also the method stopanimation must be animation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124964/discussion-between-keerthivasan-and-anahit-dev).

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to do it like this:

```
jQuery('.start_button button').click(function(event) { //This gets the button in the div

  var button = jQuery(this);

  if (buttonText(button.text()) === "Start") {
    wheelForuneAnim.startAnimation();
    button.text('Stop')
  } else {
    wheelForuneAnim.stopFull();
    setTimeout(function() {
      wheelForuneAnim.stopAnimation();
      button.text('Start')
    }, 700);
  }
})

function buttonText(text) {
  if (text === "Start") {
    return "Start"
  } else {
    return "Stop"
  }
}
```

This will not disable your button, but I think it will help you prevent that the animation breaks.

Comment: It seems to be the same situation and issue on where is the exact place for disabling the button. Any ideas? I tried with different variants but still nothing good @Zorken17. Also it is not just stop it is a different anmation on second click on that same button, that is the issue